# How to get the file-name before downloading the file

Tags: c++, download, filenames, wininet

I am trying to download a binary file from a http: server. I am using the functions `InternetOpenUrl()` and then `InternetReadFile()` to download the file. Is it possible to know the file name before downloading?

What I am doing now to get the file name is- Once the download is complete, using `GetFileVersionInfo()` and from the buffer i am getting the OrginalFilename, then renaming the file to the OrginalFilename.

Is there any other way to get the file name before downloading?

Thanks

Vinod

Answer (score 1):

Look at `HttpQueryInfo`. Look at the `Content-Type` and `Content-Disposition` headers.

You may have to use `HTTP_QUERY_CUSTOM` to get raw content-type if it just returns e.g. "text/plain".

To get all the headers (and thereby work out which one contains the information you want) you can use `HTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF`.

Comment: Hi Ben thanks for the reply. I tried to download the mozila firefox and used HTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF to get all headers , but i cannot get the file name from it these are the headers i got HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache
X-Backend-Server: ftp4.dmz.scl3.mozilla.com
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
ETag: "d0525-44c40-4e7046b6c7cc0"
Last-Modified: Mon, 23 Sep 2013 03:14:35 GMT
Content-Length: 281664
X-Cache-Info: cached
Expires: Sat, 28 Sep 2013 17:43:35 GMT
Date: Sat, 28 Sep 2013 06:03:37 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

Comment: But when I download from the web browser the file name is showing as Firefox Setup Stub 24.0.exe

Comment: @VinodPaul have you looked on browser's F12 tools network tab to see what the headers are there?

Comment: no when i paste the link , it suddenly starts downloading. This is the link- https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/24.0/win32/en-US/Firefox%20Setup%20Stub%2024.0.exe

Comment: @VinodPaul, 1) What is the URL? 2) why don't you try using the F12 tools to see what headers the server is sending?